Unable to get Firebase server key for Amplify pinpoint push notification
I'm using Amplify Pinpoint for push notifications and implementing the FCM notification method. When I attempt to add the notification service through amplify add notifications, it asks me to input the server key.
Due to Firebase's recent update regarding push notifications, the server key authorization will no longer be supported after June 20, 2024. As a result, newly created Firebase projects no longer come with a server key.
see image
I tried to enable the server key through the following option:
see image,
but encountered the following error:
see image
Please assist me with this matter if you have any leads.
